# Beanstalkd or other job/message queue : Send a file?

Tags: file, file-upload, message-queue, beanstalkd, job-queue

We were looking for a job/message queue technology.
After comparing the main ones (RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, Apollo, ZeroMQ..), we chose Beanstalkd because apparently, compared to RabbitMQ, *"It gives 80% the functionality with 20% the weight and complexity"*.

But while looking how it works, we didn't find any way to send file through this queue system.
Is there a way to achieve that ?

Maybe I should explain our situation. We've got a Web server, and a Local one. What we want to achieve with the queues, first, would be that the Web server "asks" to the Local server to generate a complex PDF, and send it back to the Web server when it's done, so it can be displayed for the visitor.

So maybe that's not the right technology for that ?

Comment: More a job for a common file system - the front end might tell the back end what name to call the generated file, and then it drops it into some location from where it can be downloaded.

Comment: Well yeah I know this alternative, but that would take more time, specially if it's shared on FTP for example..

Comment: Would there be something wrong about reading the file and sending the binary content as a message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's working perfectly just by reading file content as binary (producer) and writing it on filesystem (consumer), doesn't need any other technology (ftp, shared fs, etc).